# Invalid for loop in a function

Tags: postgresql, function, loops

I am trying to make the following function working:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_count(devices TEXT[], campaign_id INTEGER) RETURNS void AS $$
  DECLARE
    devices_array TEXT[]  := devices;
    devices_count INTEGER := array_length(devices, 1);
    row_id        INTEGER := campaign_id;
  BEGIN
    FOR device IN unnest(devices_array) LOOP
      IF my_count('my_table', device, row_id) != 1;
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'invalid_count %', row_id
      ENDIF
    END LOOP;
  END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

`my_count` is a working function which returns INTEGER.

The definition fails with the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "unnest"
LINE 7:           FOR device IN unnest(devices_array) LOOP
```

Could you spot the issue? Thanks!

I am planning to call the function as follows:

```
select validate_count('{foo, bar}', 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [FOREACH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) loop:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_count(devices TEXT[], campaign_id INTEGER) 
  RETURNS void 
AS 
$$
DECLARE
  device text;
  devices_count INTEGER := array_length(devices, 1);
BEGIN
  FOREACH device IN ARRAY devices LOOP
    IF my_count('my_table', device, campaign_id) <> 1 then
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'invalid_count %', campaign_id;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I fixed the `;` to use `THEN` but it's still fails on syntax.. could you please check why? thx in advance!

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: sorry, forgot to declare the loop variable. Btw: there is no need to re-assign the parameters. You can just use them directly.

Answer (score 1):

A few things need to be fixed to make this valid.

The `FOR` loop needs `SELECT` before the `unnest`, i.e.:

```
FOR device IN SELECT unnest(devices_array) LOOP
```

You need to declare `device` up top, for example:

```
DECLARE device RECORD;
```

The `IF` statement needs a `THEN` instead of a `;`, i.e.:

```
IF my_count('my_table', device, row_id) != 1 THEN
```

The `RAISE EXCEPTION` statement needs a semicolon at the end of the line, i.e.:

```
RAISE EXCEPTION 'invalid_count %', row_id;
```

The `END` for the `IF` statement should be `END IF;`.

The `END` for the `LOOP` statement should be `END LOOP;`.

Here's the net result:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_count(devices TEXT[], campaign_id INTEGER) RETURNS void AS $$
  DECLARE
    devices_array TEXT[]  := devices;
    devices_count INTEGER := array_length(devices, 1);
    row_id        INTEGER := campaign_id;
    device        RECORD;
  BEGIN
    FOR device IN SELECT unnest(devices_array) LOOP
      IF my_count('my_table', device, row_id) != 1 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'invalid_count %', row_id;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanation! After fixes it says `loop variable of loop over rows must be a record or row variable or list of scalar variables`

Comment: Did you `DECLARE device RECORD;` up top (without typos)?  This is the error message when `device` isn't known to the parser.

Comment: I have just done that actually, yes now it says `ERROR:  unrecognized RAISE statement option at or near "array_length"
LINE 11: ...ays have either 0 or %s of device bid modifiers', array_leng...`... (it's a hint I use with exceptions)

Comment: Not sure about that last error.  I added the whole result (which runs successfully for me) to my answer.